# Renaming Multiples Files To delete first portion of name

Tags: bash, shell, batch-file, file-rename

I have a list of files like so :

```
10_I_am_here_001.jpg
20_I_am_here_003.jpg
30_I_am_here_008.jpg
40_I_am_here_004.jpg
50_I_am_here_009.jpg
60_I_am_here_002.jpg
70_I_am_here_005.jpg
80_I_am_here_006.jpg
```

How can I rename all the files in a directory, so that I can drop `^[0-9]+_` from the filename ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pure BASH:

```
s='10_I_am_here_001.jpg'
echo "${s#[0-9]*_}"
I_am_here_001.jpg
```

You can then write a simple for loop in that directory like this:

```
for s in *; do
    f="${s#[0-9]*_}" && mv "$s" "$f"
done
```

Comment: This actually deletes `^[0-9][^_]*_` from the filename. Consider `s='1hello world_I_am_here_001.jpg'`

Comment: @thatotherguy: Your point well taken but OP showed all the file using similar pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Using `rename` :

```
rename 's/^[0-9]+_//' *
```

Comment: This requires the Perl style rename as found on Debian derivatives like Ubuntu. It doesn't work on other Linux distros or other OS.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another bash idea based on files ending .jpg as shown above or whatever>
VonBell

```
#!/bin/bash
ls *.jpg |\
while read FileName
do
    NewName="`echo $FileName | cut -f2- -d "_"`"
    mv $FileName $NewName
done
```

Answer (score 0):

With bash extended globbing

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in *
do
   [[ $f == +([0-9])_*.jpg ]] && mv "$f" "${f#+([0-9])_}"
done
```